# Behaviour with files and long loading times

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, nhibernate

I'm trying to send a file using a MVCWindowsForms Application to pick the file and NHibernate as ORM to save the file into the database. So far so good, good plan and using Test-Driven Development I'm sure on the right side. My test succeeded, but when I try uploading something directly through the app, it takes a lot of time to load and I even get debugger Deadlock Warnings.

I'm using the following configuration:

```
public EmailAttachmentMapping()
{
   Table("email_attachment");
   Id(e => e.Id, "ID");

   References(x => x.Template, "email_ID").Not.Nullable();
   Map(e => e.Title, "title").Not.Nullable();
   Map(x => x.Blob)
       //.CustomSqlType("VARBINARY (MAX) FILESTREAM")
       //.Length(2147483647)
         .Nullable();
}
```

... for my Attachments. My plan is to save the attachments seperatly from the emails cause that's kind of obvious. Faster search and lazyloading on the Attachments. So now I try the following:

```
var dummyMail = Database.LoadEmailMock();
var file = @"C:\temp\test1.docx";

EmailManager etm = new EmailManager();
EmailAttachment attachmentWithFileNameAndBlob =       
etm.CreateAttachmentWithFileNameAndBlob(emailTemplateDummy, file, Database.GetBytesFromFile(file));

dummyMail.AddAttachment(attachmentWithFileNameAndBlob);

try
{
    using (ISession session = PersistenceContext.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Save(emailTemplateDummy);
        session.Flush();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
}
```

Using a testing Situation like MS-Test and running this code results in high performance saving and reading from the database. Exactly what I needed. But now comes the thing: I'm using this in my project with windows forms and everything that appeared to be nice just got bad. The loading time is incredibly long, so I get those "ContentSwitchDeadlock" situations while only uploading 184kb into a varbinary.

Anyone got a clue what that could be? I'm in deepest debug mode and open for anything that could give me a lead how to trace the bug and to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Okay since there seems to be really no answer here, I used LINQ2SQL as workaround to handle the File Management. Seems reasonable for me. Yes I could use the Microsoft DataAdapter and QueryParameter stuff but that's up to my good experiences with Linq2SQL.

So here's the trick:

```
IList<EmailAttachment> emailAttachments = null;

using (var session = PersistenceContext.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // seperate attachments from email
    emailAttachments = model.Attachments;
    model.Attachments = null;

    session.Save(model);
    session.Flush();
    transaction.Commit();
}

//LINQ Solution to save attachments
if (emailTemplateAttachments != null)
{
    foreach (EmailAttachment attachment in emailAttachments)
    {
        FileHelperDBDataContext context = new FileHelperDBDataContext(_connectionString);
        LinqEmailAttachment linqClone = new LinqEmailAttachment();
        linqClone.blob = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(attachment.Blob);
        linqClone.title = attachment.Title;
        linqClone.email_template_ID = model.Id;

        context.LinqEmailTemplateAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(linqClone);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```